# Can I use Magento's Caching layer as a Key/Value Store?

Tags: php, caching, magento

Can I use Magento's Caching layer as a Key/Value Store similar to memcached or apc?  It be nice to be able to not worry what caching engine is being used and still cache some of the code.

On a further note, I will expect Magento to cache my Collection after I do some JOINS with it.  If for some reason Magento does not cache the joined data, I'd like to hear about that as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The cache can be used directly as a key/value store,
https://web.archive.org/web/20040328220156/http://www.nicksays.co.uk/2010/07/developers-guide-magento-cache/
<sup>(Thanks to [B00MER](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158325/b00mer) for [pointing this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142508/magento-block-caching/5146460#5146460))</sup>

Blocks already have some caching functionality built in, you just need to [provide the key](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/block_cache_and_html_ouput). <strike>Collections don't have the same trick but</strike> MySQL does have it's own [query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) and may already be active. Block caching is preferred since your collection will often end up as rendered HTML anyway.

Edit:
Collections **can** be cached and like blocks need a cache key. I've not done it before but presumably it works exactly the same.

(It has [been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3755104/471559) but not answered)

Comment: Thanks clockworkgeek, that link is very helpful.  Pertaining your second statement, Why is there an option in Cache Management for "Collections Data" if Magento does not cache collections?

Comment: I was wrong. When looking for some clearer information (and there isn't much) I noticed someone else answered with the same link as I: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/221710/ Uncanny!

Comment: +1 you are awesome clockworkgeek!  I really appreciate your advice on SO

Comment: Did you get collection cache to work? Since it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere you might be pioneering a new technique! (Albeit within a very specialised area of interest)

Comment: Thanks for the credit, however the real credit belongs to: Nick Jones @ Meanbee.

Comment: Nick's post can be found here, without the need of archive.org: 
https://www.nicksays.co.uk/developers-guide-magento-cache/